# Adding a new property to the object dynamically in a select statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, iqueryable

I need to add a new property to the object into select statement. And I know the name of the property only in runtime. I need something like this:

```
var propName = "Some name"; // calculated in runtime

// query is IQueryable
query = query.Select(item => new SomeDynamicObject(item)
{
    propName = 1
});
```

I need to have a copy of the item that has a new property with name which can be calculated in runtime. Moreover the query should be `IQueryable` because the query should be performed in a database.

I have tried to use `ExpandoObject` but it works only with `IEnumerable`:

```
var propName = "Some name"; // calculated in runtime
query.AsEnumerable().Select(item =>
{
    // ToDynamic create ExpandoObject instanse from existing object
    var expando = item.ToDynamic() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    expando.Add(propName, 1);
    return (dynamic)expando;
});
```

In the end I want to sort by this new property using `Expression.Call()`.

How can I do that using `IQueryable`? Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve. Can't you filter on the queryable _before_ the `AsEnumerable` call?

Comment: In the end I want to sort by this new property using Expression.Call().

Comment: @Neshta if you need it only for sorting, you just need to generate expression for this calculated property and pass to OrderBy. Otherwise looks like EntityFramework/Sql do not fit your needs very well or you're trying to reinvent the wheel for your specific task.

Comment: I think this maybe an XY solution, What are you trying to achieve at a high level?

Comment: @CallumLinington I try to solve an issue with Kendo MVC grid. There is a problem with sorting enums that can be localized and has different order in different languages. Ticket was created more then 3 years ago and it is still not fixed. [Link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/mvc-kendo-grid-sorting-enum) to the ticket.
I try to add to the`query` additional property which can be used for ordering in a database.